# What sentence is suitable for thanking a professor?

Tags: phd, etiquette, communication

I am looking for a PhD position. Sometimes professors give me information about their projects via emails. How can I thank them for their explanation in a polite way, show my interest and impress them?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: professors are people too. You can thank them just like thanking anyone else. Your email may go something like this:

> Dear Professor X,
>
> Thank you for the information about your PhD project. I look forward to submitting my formal application to your department.
>
> Best wishes,
>
> maryam

Comment: I am not  an native English speaker, I fear that I express my gratitude in informal way, that's why I asked such a question.

Answer (score 2):

Natalie Hogg's answer is spot-on. I want to address a further aspect of the question:

> How can I thank them for their explanation in a polite way, show my interest and **impress them**?

While impressing your potential advisor is certainly a desirable goal, the chances of impressing a professor with a thank-you e-mail are close to zero. A professor is more likely to by impressed by an applicant if the application itself is impressive, for example, because it includes convincing arguments why your particular skills and experiences will help their work group produce good research.

Comment: maybe I should have asked my question in a different way,
I wanted to thank for her(professor) explanation, and then express my interest to her project. as, I am not a native English speaker, I am look for the best sentences that show my interest and gratitude.

Comment: @maryam You are possibly overthinking this. Politeness is good, but a polite thank-you e-mail will not significantly change the professor's attitude towards you. It would be more productive to focus on preparing strong applications.